# accessing variable in parent page from iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a page with an iframe that contains a html page. I want to access a Javascript variable in the parent page from within the iframe. The name of the variable in the main page is `observer`.

I have tried this

```
parent.observer = 'aadasds';
```

but I am getting the following error:

> Permission denied for  to get property Window.observer
>   from

.

Comment: Can we see some code / a link?

Comment: A code example would be helpful. However, I believe you can only access a variable in the parent page if it's from the same domain. If the iframe exists on a different domain than the parent, that may be the source of your problem.

Comment: http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exchanging values between iframes (and parent) is only allowed if both sites come from the same domain. If they do, your example should just work. If they don't, browsers inhibit the communication.

However there are a number of hacks to circumvent this: e.g the Yahoo.CrossFrame library described in [Julien le Comte's blog](http://www.julienlecomte.net/blog/2007/11/31/) using a third iframe to enable one way communication, or the "resize an iframe around the iframe"-idea described in [Adam Fortuna's blog](http://adamfortuna.com/2009/09/30/resize-a-crossdomain-iframe/) enabling two way communication.

**Edit** (as people still seem to read this old answer):
In modern Browsers you can use [postMessage](http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging) to exchange Data between iframes. There are many javascript libraries that try to emulate that functionality in older browsers, too. E.g. by mis-using the location.hash, like the [jquery-postmessage-plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/) does.

Comment: "Exchanging values between iframes (and parent) is only allowed if both sites come from the same domain. If they do, your example should just work. If they don't, browsers inhibit the communication." - can a javascript function on the page be called from the page inside the iframe?

Comment: @Niall Collins: Yes, without problems - as long as both pages come from the same domain. The error message you describe only appears if they originate from different domains, as far as I know.

Comment: How would you answer the question if the iframes where the same domain?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though  your iframes are using different domains. All major browsers block access to parent iframes if they are not using the same domain. IE if you have the domain `www.test.com` and you embedded a page from `www.google.com` and try to access/modify anything from google's website, you will be denied access.

The other answer to this question explains the implemented API `post message`. This can also be used to send/receive data from different frames from different domains. However, the things you can do with that are limited compared to if you had two frames using the same domain.

That being said, here is the answer if your iframes are using the same domain.

```
window.parent.observer;
```

Hope this helps someone :)