# Call javascript of another page in ajax xmlHttp.open

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a jsp  page DEMO1.jsp in which i have written ajax code to refresh every 1 minutes.In DEMO1.JSP I HAVE

```
<head>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        setInterval(function(){
            document.getElementById('bgframe').contentWindow.myInternalFunction();
        }, 5*1000);

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="AutoRefreshValid();"  style="margin:1px;font-family: Serif, Arial,Times, serif;" id="ValidWaybills"><center>

    <iframe id='bgframe' style='display:none;' src='DEMO2.jsp'></iframe>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function AutoRefreshValid(){
            var xmlHttp;
            try{
                xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();// Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
            }
            catch (e){
                try{
                    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // Internet Explorer
                }
                catch (e){
                    try{
                        xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    catch (e){
                        alert("No AJAX");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
                    document.getElementById('ValidWaybills1Valid').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
                    setTimeout('AutoRefreshValid()',5*1000);
                }
            }

            xmlHttp.open("GET","DEMO2.jsp",true);
            xmlHttp.send(null);



        }
    </script>
    <div  id="ValidWaybills1Valid">

    </div>
```

I HAVE DEMO2.JSP WHERE I HAVE WRITTEN JAVASCRIPT 
I HAVE TO RUN THAT JAVASCRIPT USING AJAX IN DEMO1.JSP WITHOUT RELOADING THE PAGE EVERY 5 SECONDS

```
<head>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function callme3(){

        <%  Date d1 = new Date();
        %>
                alert("Date is          <%=d1%>");
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="callme3()">



</div>
```

Thanks and regads 
Sudarshan

Comment: Why you want to do this? update a part of the page or?

Comment: I have to implement this for updating the google marker in google map without reloading the page .using this concept only

Comment: Sorry to ask, can you show some actual code you use in your page? like how you update the google map? Say you have the google map embeded on demo1.jsp, and you want to update the marker on it. What you have to do is to retrieve the data needed to update it like parameters to the Google Map's API and call it from demo1.jsp, rather than call it from script from another page.

Comment: Thanku i am explaining the original code .I have google map in DEMO2.jsp .To display map and retrieve all marker from database i have written code in javascipt of DEMO2.jsp.Just to update marker i have to interact to database every 5 second for that i have to relode using ajax so only marker should update.How to do that please suggest me

Comment: Markers are updating in database if new points has come my map should show that point without reloading the map.

Comment: If i am calling from the same page also the markers are not updating

Comment: updated the solution. and check out the google [example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple) if you have further question.

Comment: Please revise your question/title to reflect the actual question, so that the discussion could be helpful to other people.

Answer (score 1):

An XML Http Request is about send something and retrieve some something. Executing the retrieved data is not part of its job.

Here is a naive/simple solution to your problem, but NOT recommend you to do so.

```
xmlHttp.open("GET", "SU3.jsp", true);
xmlHttp.onload = function(evt) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = evt.target.responseText;
  document.body.appendChild(div);
};
xmlHttp.send(null);
```

This code will eventually crash the browser, after a long time.

The right way to do this is to make SU3.jsp return data in json or plain html and move all the logic to SU2.jsp.

---

Based on the latest info you provide (which should be provided at the very first version,) the solution is pretty neat and simple.

on Su2.jsp, add the following code:

```
// assume map refers to the map object.
// and I use jQuery here to make the point clear, 
// it's ok to use XmlHttpRequest directly.

var timer = null;

function updateMarker() {

  $.get('su3.jsp', function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var datum = data[i];
      new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(datum.pos.lat, datum.pos.lng),
        title: datum.title
      });
    }
    // after all jobs are done, set timeout for another update.
    // use setTimeout() instead of setInterval() to tolerate net latency.
    timer = setTimeout(updateMaker, 5000);
  });

}

// this should be called in onLoad() handler.
updateMaker();
```

on SU3.jsp, you should output the data using `Content-Type: application/json`. which outputs makers info as:

```
[{"pos":{"lat":-25.363882,"lng":131.044922},"title":"Australia"}]
```

Comment: Please suggest me to run the javascript of su3.jsp page to run through su2.jsp page without reloading the page using ajax.

Comment: Thanks i m posting it once again

Comment: @SudarshanThakur Better to give a demo link.

Comment: I am writing code in local host so i m not able to provide link

Comment: Thanku very much but i dont know json and how to use it .Do i need to write datanase code in json only

Comment: nonono, json is like XML, they are just used to transmit data over internet. store them as what they suppose to be, and output them with JSON en/decode lib after pull out from db.

Comment: Thanku but i cant get u.Please send me some sample code .I am doing this since past six month.Do i have to remove the ajax code in su2.jsp and keep that google map code

Comment: Or please send me some link to follow

Comment: Find some professional to help you with your code. I really don't know how to be more helpful other than write entire code for you. : )

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to execute javascript from SU3.jsp you could call it via a hidden iframe in SU2.jsp

Add the following JavaScript/Markup to SU2.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript'>

    setInterval(function(){
        document.getElementById('bgframe').contentWindow.location.reload();
    },60000); // reload every 60 seconds

  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id='bgframe' style='display:none;' src='SU3.jsp'></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Remember that if SU3.jsp requires access to functions/variables within its parent (SU2.jsp) you will need to use *window.parent* as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886410/accessing-variable-in-parent-page-from-iframe)

If on the otherhand you just need to call a JavaScript function within SU3.jsp every 60 seconds you can do so like this:

```
document.getElementById('bgframe').contentWindow.myInternalFunction();

setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById('bgframe').contentWindow.myInternalFunction();
}, 60000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply it is working but the problem is that the page is reloading.I dont need that that thats why i am using ajax.please suggest me how to run javascript of su3.jsp page without reloading the whole page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply it is working but the problem is that the page is reloading.I dont needto reload the page, thats why i am using ajax.please suggest me how to run javascript of su3.jsp page without reloading the whole page.

Comment: Updated answer with example on how to call a hypothetical function called 'myInternalFunction' inside SU3.jsp

Comment: Thanks but the bellow code document.getElementById('bgframe').contentWindow.myInternalFunction();runs only once i need to run it every 1 minutes without reloading the page

Comment: You need to use setInterval as explained in the previous code block, I updated the second block for clarity

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply sir but this function setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById('bgframe').contentWindow.myInternalFunction();
}, 60000);is not running more than once.

Comment: check code inside SU3.jsp, something is probably wrong in the function you're calling. Here's a simple jsfiddle which shows setInterval in action every 1 second http://jsfiddle.net/KM3eZ/

Comment: Same i want to do for my page to reload without refresh .

Comment: You almost have solved my problem i just need to run javascript without realoding the page .

Comment: if this line is still in your code, remove it.   document.getElementById('bgframe').contentWindow.location.reload();

Comment: I have now  setInterval(function(){
                document.getElementById('bgframe').contentWindow.myInternalFunction();
            }, 5*1000);in my code

Comment: please provide some code otherwise this discussion will go on forever. thanks