# iFrame link not directly accessable

Tags: javascript, iframe, replace, url-rewriting, assign

I have the following situation.

On my website I have a paid subscription where customers can login and view a html5 flipbook of a pdf. This I do by using iFrames. Problem is, the link is being spread to non-paying people, which is what I would like to prevent. I used JS to block people from inspecting the code, for as far as I possibly could. So that is somewhat taken care of. But Apple being Apple, it doesn't really iFrames and does its own thing. When you open the flipbook in full screen it displays the URL and that's being spread again. Both the iFrame and the actual flipbook are running on the same server and domain.

My question is, is there a way to prevent the URL from opening when it gets accessed directly but still open in an iFrame? Or am I trying to achieve the impossible? Perhaps you have a better solution for me?

Let me know please, I am open for everything.

PJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To those that seek the answer as well. I did the following.

```
function CheckIframe() {
        var defaultUrl = "Redirect URL";
        if (window.parent.location == document.location) {
            alert("Incorrectly loaded");
            document.location = defaultUrl;
        }
    }
```

The opening  tag has the onload="CheckIframe()" in it.

Basically, when you open the link outside of the iframe it gives an alert and once you close the alert you get redirected to the defaultUrl.

Of course the client can turn off JS in their browser but it's something.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using encrypted data inside the iframe and a script that decodes the data by using a variable in the parent page.

This can be done only if both the resources are under the same domain, the same protocol and the same port. (read something about CORS).

So, you're supposed to:

- Make a page with the iframe inside and the key to decrypt the data. The data has to be encrypted on every request with a new key.
- Create a script in the page that is shown in the iframe, that script should decrypt the page data with the key retrieved in the parent page.

Look this little script to understand better:

```
// In your page
window.key = 'KEY';

// In your iframe
window.encrypted = 'The encrypted data that you will show to the user';

window.decrypt = function() {
    // Here you should get window.key
    // Then you have to decrypt window.encrypted
    // When you finished, you should show the result to the user
}
```

Check also the tec's answer to this question: [accessing variable in parent page from iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886410/accessing-variable-in-parent-page-from-iframe)

Comment: I wouldn't be needing CORS as I am not crossing anything, both are running on my server on my domain. My JavaScript is very very basic so I can't really get anywhere with the script that is provided..